# Filter query with relative hour range

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

Im trying to write a query to give me all entries starting 24 hours in the past, but not more than 25 hours in the past.

So if the date and time the query is executed is `06.17.2016 15:00` I want to find every entry with a startdate between `06.16.2016 15:00` and `06.16.2016 15:59`

Tried using `__range` but it seems like it does not work using hours. Is it even possible doing this using `.filter()` ?

Here is my code:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    startdate = models.DateTimeField()
```

-

```
start = timezone.now().date() - relativedelta(hours=+24)
end = timezone.now().date() - relativedelta(hours=+25)

list = Entry.objects.filter(startdate__gte=start, startdate__lte=end)
```

## Edit:

list gives a empty queryset.

## Edit 2:

Seems to be a problem whith `relativedelta`

`start = timezone.now().date() - relativedelta(hours=+24, seconds=+1)` gives me
`datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 16, 0, 59, 59)`

`end = timezone.now().date() - relativedelta(hours=+25, seconds=+1)` gives me
`datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 15, 22, 59, 59)`

Need to fix that if I want it to work, I guess.

Comment: What's wrong with your approach?

Comment: Not sure what could be wrong, but I only get a empty queryset when I try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were calculating the wrong range. Your start is 24 hours ago, end is within 25 hours ago, you should have start as 25 hours ago and end as 24 hours ago.

```
start = timezone.now().date() - relativedelta(hours=+25)
end = timezone.now().date() - relativedelta(hours=+24)
list = Entry.objects.filter(startdate__gte=start, startdate__lte=end)
```

Other things that are problematic in your code, you shouldn't using `timezone.now().date()` to calculate the time range, because your field is `DateTimeField` and you are dealing with hours, so `date` is clearly not granular enough(even though it's still sort of working using `date()`, but the concept is wrong):

```
start = timezone.now() - relativedelta(hours=+25)
end = timezone.now() - relativedelta(hours=+24)
```

Also, please **always** state your problem clearly in the body of the question, like you were having empty queryset, it will make others easier to judge what problem do you have.